# Make fields inside a JSON response clickable (url) on a JSP page

Tags: html, json, jsp

I wish to display the JSON response returned from a REST API call "as-is" on a JSP. The problem I'm facing here is that the response is in a single line like below.

```
{"result":[{"enable":"true","time_stamp":"2018-01-26 19:31:37","url":"abc.xyz.com","group_id":"one"},{"enable":"false","time_stamp":"2018-01-26 19:31:37","url":"lmn.pqr.com","group_id":"two"}]}
```

I would like it to be displayed in a well-formatted JSON response, something like below for sorts.

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "enable":"true",
         "time_stamp":"2018-01-26 19:31:37",
         "url":"abc.xyz.com",
         "group_id":"one"
      },
      {  
         "enable":"false",
         "time_stamp":"2018-01-26 19:31:37",
         "url":"lmn.pqr.com",
         "group_id":"two"
      }
   ]
}
```

Having said that, there are certain url (`"url":"abc.xyz.com"`)parameters in the JSON response, which I would want to be clickable, so that users can see the JSON response dumped on the web page, but be able to click on the URL field's value to navigate to the different page.

Any idea of how this could be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

Just use `JSON.stringify` and a HTML tag of `pre` 
Here is a [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/h1odjyod/)

or if your use AngularJs use:

```
<pre>{{jsonData|json}}</pre>
```

Comment: How does that make URLs clickable?

Comment: The question is about Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: There are two questions being asked, one is how to display the long json string in a formatted way and the second question is about how to make the url part of the string clickable. I answered the first part about displaying it in a formatted way.
Plus, it's a javascript issue, not Java as you mention. The fact that it is displayed on a JSP page is not relevant.

Comment: Rendering the URL as a link **is a detail of the formatting**, it is not a separate question.

Comment: "Plus, it's a javascript issue" — No it isn't. There is no JavaScript code in the question. The question does not have the [tag:javascript] tag. The question does not mention JavaScript. The OP clearly wants to parse and format the JSON using server-side code (i.e. Java / JSP)